# Clear cache of @Schedule in EJB

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly, job-scheduling

I have a singleton class that perform an task in some time interval. When the application starts its all fine, the task is run in right period and that interval is enough suck that any task isn't overlap.

The class is show bellow:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class BOTAnalisaSituacao {
    public BOTAnalisaSituacao() throws FileNotFoundException {
    }

    @Schedule(second = "0", minute = "*/1", hour = "*")
    public void analisar() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Starting");
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }
 }
```

The web container used is Wildfly 10.

The problem is, when the application is started after one hour down, for example, the task is executed sequentially, in this case all 60 calls, after that the 1 minute period is restored by itself.
Do I have to clear any cache to avoid suck behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by "when the application is restarted after one hour down"?

Comment: The application have to be running all the time but in case of an failure all schedules tasks have to be lost. In fact I mean "When the application is started after on hour down". I add the parameter "persistence=false" to @Schedule and worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timers are persistent by default. If the server is shut down or crashes, persistent timers are saved and will become active again when the server is restarted, If a persistent timer expires while the server is down all lost timers will be called. 
Non-persistent programmatic timers are created by calling adding `persistent=false` to annotation:

```
@Schedule(second = "0", minute = "*/1", hour = "*",persistent=false)
    public void analisar() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Starting");
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }
```

source: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html#bnbpa